# Suitable abstraction for Email and SMS

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I am making a piece of software which has the ability to send out Emails and SMS messages.

My boss has asked for both facilities to go under the same heading in a dropdown menu. But I can't think of a suitable work that encapsulates both.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Dropdown menus don't need to be 1 word. "Email / SMS" seems suitable to me.

Comment: Nice thought. I hadn't even considered that.

Comment: Using an umbrella term such as "Message" gives you scope to add further message types in future.

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that requests for names of application menu choices are on a par with names for software classes, etc. - too localised.

Comment: Did you mean to say you can't think of a suitable "word"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is something like menu, the title "Send Message" may be enough. Then, from the dropdown, SMS or Mail could be chosen.

Comment: 'message' instantly conjures up SMS -- except for old-timers who are more likely to associate it with email. In fact, 'message' is often used to contrast from email.

Comment: @Kris, I have no idea about the users of that software... you may be right. My concern was the "clear instruction". The title "Email / SMS" suggested by tenfour would also be good choice.

Comment: @Kris I agree with Mustafa that 'message' covers SMS, email, Twitter DM, and many other kinds of message. Nobody thinks the M in 'JMS' refers to SMS.

Comment: This is similar to what IBM's Sametime client does. Right click on a contact and there's an option "Send>" - select that and you get the option to send announcement or email.

Answer (score 1):

*Communication* perhaps?

There is no context provided, but there may be other alternatives. For example, if you are wanting to send confirmation of an action or transaction, either via email or SMS, you could use *Send Confirmation*.

Perhaps it's a request for something? *Send Request*?

Comment: The messages themselves cover all kinds of formats- requests, confirmations, warnings, notifications, etc..

Comment: Fair enough - a more specific title clearly wont be possible, so Communication remains my only helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, the 'suitable **work** that encapsulates both' would be a verb not a noun: ***Compose***.

Thereafter, the drop down distinguishes between SMS and email anyway.

Comment: I believe "work" in the OP's question is a misspelling of "word".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case **send notifications** or simply **notify (users/customers)** could be an appropriate alternative.

Comment: The messages are not all notifications. Some are requests, confirmations etc.

Answer (score -1):

How about "**send information**"? You are sending information it could be sent through mail or SMS.